# It's possible to connect to "HTTP Long Polling server" as a "client" with .NET WebSockets?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, websocket, socket.io

I'am looking at [this sample connection](https://github.com/gigobyte/HLTV/blob/master/src/endpoints/connectToScorebot.ts) with [socket.io](https://socket.io) and I'am trying to make a client to connect on "https://scorebot-lb.hltv.org"(this not is an web socket Api) with .NET WebSockets for example.

**Sample Node.js syntax**

```
SampleConn = async () => {

    const url = 'https://scorebot-lb.hltv.org'
    const matchId = 2348837

    const socket = io.connect(url)

    const initObject = JSON.stringify({
        token: '',
        listId: matchId
    })

    let reconnected = false

    socket.on('connect', () => {

        if (!reconnected) {
            socket.emit('readyForMatch', initObject)
        }

        socket.on('scoreboard', (data) => {
            ...
        })

        socket.on('log', (data) => {
            ...
        })

        socket.on('fullLog', (data) => {
            ...
        })
    })

    return "";
};
```

This sample in Node.js works perfectly. But in my tentatives with .NET defaults, the sockets configurations wants a "ws://" or "wss://" urls and if you try to put "https://scorebot-lb.hltv.org" we got some errors, like:

```
1 - HostNotFound;
2 - System.ArgumentException: 'The scheme part isn't 'ws' or 'wss': https://scorebot-lb.hltv.org';
3 - System.ArgumentException: 'Not an absolute URI: scorebot-lb.hltv.org';
```

**Others tests, but without success:**

[**WebSocketSharp**](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     using (var ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("scorebot-lb.hltv.org"))
     {
          ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
             Console.WriteLine("...");

          ws.Connect();
          ws.Send("...");
          Console.ReadKey(true);
     }
}
```

**[**SocketIOSharp**](https://github.com/uhm0311/SocketIOSharp#client)**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new SocketIOClientOption(EngineIOScheme.http, "scorebot-lb.hltv.org", 80);
            var client = new SocketIOClient(options);

            client.Connect();

            client.On("connect", () => {

                client.Emit("readyForMatch", "{'token':'','listId':2348837}");

                client.On("scoreboard", () => {});

                client.On("log", () => { });

                client.On("fullLog", () => { });
            });

            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the path? It's possible?

***[UPDATE]***

In short, no it's not possible. Before I wrote this question, I didn't know that HLTV score board used socket.io(I thought it was something related to HTTP Long Polling), so, we need a socket.io client library to do this. Please check my answer.

Comment: What happened when you used `wss` as the error says? That’s the correct URL scheme for TLS websockets

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what you think it is. If you [search the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22hltv.org%22+%22websocket%22+server) for a websocket service for hltv.org, nothing comes up. Can you direct us to the Websocket API for hltv.org? Maybe i'm not looking for the right thing. That nuget package you mention is just a web-scraper project. They probably created their own custom websocket server based on the scraper code.

Comment: @Andy yes there is no officially API or Websocket API for HLTV. The Node.js library scrap match page and "connect to scorebot". If socket.io can make this, why the SocketIOSharp (SocketIOSharp is a Socket.IO protocol revision 4 library) cannot?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what format do you meaning? `wss://scorebot-lb.hltv.org`?

Comment: @Igor Yep, just replace https with wss and then it’s a valid TLS websockets URL

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen this url is probably a "HTTP long-polling", its not emmit "socket handshake" for example. Error: "WebSocket.doHandshake|Not a WebSocket handshake response.".

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with owner of [The unofficial HLTV Node.js API](https://github.com/gigobyte/HLTV) repo, and he tells me:

> HLTV uses socket-io, **so that's not possible**. You need to connect with a socket-io client otherwise it's not going to work.

In this case, I made a connection as a client with [SocketIOSharp](https://github.com/uhm0311/SocketIOSharp)(mentioned before on question), and the implementation is it:

```
using System; 
using SocketIOSharp.Client; 
using SocketIOSharp.Common; 
using EngineIOSharp.Common.Enum;
    
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var socketIOClient = 
                new SocketIOClient(new SocketIOClientOption(EngineIOScheme.http, "scorebot-lb.hltv.org", 80));
    
            InitEventHandlers(socketIOClient);            
    
            socketIOClient.Connect();
          
            Console.Read();
        }
    
        static void InitEventHandlers(SocketIOClient socketIOClient)
        {
            socketIOClient.On(SocketIOEvent.CONNECTION, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                socketIOClient.Emit("readyForMatch", "{'token':'','listId':2348897}");
            });
    
            socketIOClient.On(SocketIOEvent.DISCONNECT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected!");
            });
    
            //Sample event...
            socketIOClient.On("scoreboard", (Data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Data[0]);
            });
        } }
```

With this implementation, the things works now ‍✔️!